# Combining Swiper slider and photoswipe

Tags: modal-dialog, slider, photoswipe, swiper.js

I'm looking for a combination of Swiper slider and Photoswipe (Or other  lightbox).

Trying to make a product slider with 3 products in a slide.

Each product has a lightbox/modal with video and a gallery.
The modals are generated within the boundaries of the product div.
When you click an 'open gallery' / 'show video' link. The lightbox opens fullscreen.

The problem I'm having is: the lightbox won't (but has to) exceed the boundary of the slider product boundary.

Looking for a solution.

Something like an empty modal/lightbox containers outside the slider with dynamic content when an 'open modal' link is clicked within the product slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it, here is example:

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <a title="swiper.js" href="http://idangero.us/swiper/" target="_blank">Swiper.js (5.3.7)</a> &
    <a title="photoswipe" href="http://photoswipe.com/" target="_blank">Photoswipe.js (4.1.3)</a> - Mobile Native feel
    slider gallery
  </h1>
  <p>Combine two of the most powerfull JS plugins (Endless options / Great docs / Fast / Modern / Mobile freindly) -
    <a title="swiper.js" href="http://idangero.us/swiper/" target="_blank">SWIPER</a> IS PERFECT FOR THIS IDEA BEACUSE OF
    ITS unique <code>preventClicks</code> Parameter (Prevent accidental unwanted clicks on links during swiping) -
    <strong>Works like magic</strong>. Also its really <b>hard</b> to find - Code example of working photoswipe
    combination with any slider out there(slick, flickity, owl etc.) and
    in general slider & lightbox - so i hope this example be usefull for you.</p>
</header>

<!-- https://swiperjs.com/get-started/ -->
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <ul class="swiper-wrapper my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <li id="1" class="swiper-slide" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a id="first" title="click to zoom-in" href="https://picsum.photos/id/1079/1200/600" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1200x600">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1079/1200/600" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="2" class="swiper-slide" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a title="click to zoom-in" href="http://placehold.it/1200x601/AB47BC/ffffff?text=Zoom-image-2"
         itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1200x601">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300/AB47BC/ffffff?text=Thumbnail-image-2" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="3" class="swiper-slide" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a title="click to zoom-in" href="http://placehold.it/1200x600/EF5350/ffffff?text=Zoom-image-3" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1200x600">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300/EF5350/ffffff?text=Thumbnail-image-3" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="4" class="swiper-slide" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a title="click to zoom-in" href="http://placehold.it/1200x600/1976D2/ffffff?text=Zoom-image-4" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1200x600">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300/1976D2/ffffff?text=Thumbnail-image-4" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="5" class="swiper-slide" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a title="click to zoom-in" href="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/1200/600" itemprop="contentUrl"
         data-size="1200x600">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/1200/600" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div title="Prev" class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div title="Next" class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>

<!-- https://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html -->
<!-- add PhotoSwipe (.pswp) element to DOM - 
    Root element of PhotoSwipe. Must have class pswp. -->
<div class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

  <!-- Background of PhotoSwipe. 
          It's a separate element, as animating opacity is faster than rgba(). -->
  <div class="pswp__bg"></div>

  <!-- Slides wrapper with overflow:hidden. -->
  <div class="pswp__scroll-wrap">

    <!-- Container that holds slides. PhotoSwipe keeps only 3 slides in DOM to save memory. -->
    <!-- don't modify these 3 pswp__item elements, data is added later on. -->
    <div class="pswp__container">
      <div class="pswp__item"></div>
      <div class="pswp__item"></div>
      <div class="pswp__item"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Default (PhotoSwipeUI_Default) interface on top of sliding area. Can be changed. -->
    <div class="pswp__ui pswp__ui--hidden">

      <div class="pswp__top-bar">

        <!--  Controls are self-explanatory. Order can be changed. -->

        <div class="pswp__counter"></div>

        <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" title="Close (Esc)"></button>

        <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--share" title="Share"></button>

        <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--fs" title="Toggle fullscreen"></button>

        <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--zoom" title="Zoom in/out"></button>

        <!-- Preloader demo https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/yyBWoR -->
        <!-- element will get class pswp__preloader--active when preloader is running -->
        <div class="pswp__preloader">
          <div class="pswp__preloader__icn">
            <div class="pswp__preloader__cut">
              <div class="pswp__preloader__donut"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="pswp__share-modal pswp__share-modal--hidden pswp__single-tap">
        <div class="pswp__share-tooltip"></div>
      </div>

      <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--left" title="Previous (arrow left)">
      </button>

      <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--right" title="Next (arrow right)">
      </button>

      <div class="pswp__caption">
        <div class="pswp__caption__center"></div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<!-- ////////////////////////
    DOCS
    ////////////////////////////
    -->

<!-- Include Tippy -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@3/dist/tippy.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- OPTIONAL: Set the defaults for the auto-initialized tooltips -->
<script>
  tippy('.swiper-button-prev', { 
    content: "Prev",
    theme: "light",
    arrow: true,
  })

  tippy('.swiper-button-next', { 
    content: "Next",
    theme: "light",
    arrow: true,
  })
</script>


<section id="docs">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <h2>Noted / Important</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>
      <h3>
        A non-jQuery dependent
      </h3>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Cdns</h3>
      <h4>Head (CSS)</h4>
      <code>
        &lt;!-- photoswipe CSS --&gt;
        <br>
        &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.3/photoswipe.min.css&quot; /&gt;
        <br>
        &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.3/default-skin/default-skin.min.css&quot; /&gt;
        <br>
        &lt;!-- swiper CSS --&gt;
        <br>
        &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css&quot; /&gt;
      </code>
      <h4>Before body (JS)</h4>
      <code>
        &lt;script src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.3/photoswipe.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
        <br>
        &lt;script src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.3/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
        <br>
        &lt;script src=&quot;https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
        <br>
        &lt;!-- copy-paste the code under codepen js tab her (wrap with script tag) --&gt;
      </code>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Loop & Counter</h3>
      <p>
        <strong> Wont work well </strong> with swiper: <code>loop = true;</code> & photoswipe: <code>counterEl:
        true,</code>(What is counter? example: 1/5...2/5) - "loop" duplicate images - the photoswipe counter will be
        wrong. *** If you dont want a
        loop - you can set photoswipe counter <code>counterEl: true,</code>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3><a target="_blank" href="https://schema.org/ImageGallery">Schema.org - ImageGallery</a> Markup (0 ERRORS 0 WARNINGS )</h3>
      <p>
        <a href="">Schema.org</a> markup + semantic HTML: use unordered (bulleted) list (If you want a <code>div</code> under photoswipe - change JS -
        <strong>"(find) control+f-->"</strong> tagname value) . Copy-paste - this code to check: <a target="_blank"
                                                                                                    href="https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool">Structured Data Testing Tool - Google</a>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Match index - BY API</h3>
      <p>
        <strong>
          Extra CODE "match index"
        </strong> - EXAMPLE: When you click(zoom) image1 -- goes to image 2 - close image2 (X) - also the swiper update
        is position (<strong>BETTER</strong> User Experience) (find<kbd>(ctr +f)</kbd>-->
        <code>mySwiper.slideTo(getCurrentIndex, false);</code>) -
        This idea miss
        in most slider & lightbox examples/plugins mixed.
        <br>
        Very simple code idea (100% API solution) - get photoswipe index (for example 2) and swiper slideTo index (2 - in this example).
      <ul>
        <li >
          <a target="_blank" href="https://photoswipe.com/documentation/api.html">Photoswipe API - <strong>pswp.getCurrentIndex()</strong></a>
        <li style="border-top-width: 0;"> <a target="_blank" href="https://swiperjs.com/api/#methods">Swiper API - <strong>slideTo(index);</strong></a>
        </li>

        </li>
    </ul>

  </p>
</li>
<li>
  <h3>Photoswipe options</h3>
  <p>
    JS - line (find) -ctr +f --> the term:<code>// define options (if needed)</code>. You find endless options for
    <strong>photoswipe</strong> - This is the place to add/modify options. Full Options list her
    <a href="http://photoswipe.com/documentation/options.html" target="_blank">PhotoSwipe
      Options</a>
  </p>
</li>

<li>
  <h3>SWIPER options</h3>
  <h4>slideperview</h4>
  <p>
    <code>slideperview</code> - option1: Set number (1,2,3 and so on) <a
                                                                         href="http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/110-slides-per-view.html" target="_blank"> - example </a> |||||
    option2(<b>"Carousel Mode"</b> this example): Set to "<code>auto</code>"
    than add CSS <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp" target="_blank">width
    Property</a></code> <code>.swiper-slide</code> (in thie case eash slide is 88% width) - <a
                                                                                               href="http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/120-slides-per-view-auto.html" target="_blank">example</a>.
</p>
<h4>spaceBetween & centeredSlides</h4>
<p>
  Space Between slide by js option <code>spaceBetween</code> - and also usefull to change
  <code>centeredSlides</code>(true/flase). <br>
  <a href="http://idangero.us/swiper/api/" target="_blank">Swiper API</a>
</p>
</li>
</ol>
<hr>
<h3>Related Example</h3>
<p>
  <a title="FancyBox3 & Flickity" href="https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/OQmjoq" target="_blank">#FancyBox3 -
    lightbox & Flickity Slider</a>
</p>
</section>
```

```css
/* zero custom styles for photoswipe */

/*==================================
SWIPER - minimal styling
===================================*/
/* semantic HTML - remove bullet and space from the list */
ul.swiper-wrapper {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Swiper container */
.swiper-container {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* swiper responive image */
.swiper-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
  /* Remove this if you want 1 slide perview - than change slidesPerView js-option to 1 -or- 2+ instead of 'auto' */
  width: 80%;
}

/* Swiper custom pagination */
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 34px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease, color 0.5s ease;
}

/* Swiper custom pagination */
.swiper-pagination-bullet:hover {
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: white;
}

/* Swiper custom pagination active state */
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  color: #fff;
  background: black;
}


/*==================================================================
CODEPEN STYLES -(under codepen gear/setting icon)
==============================================++++++================*/
.tippy-tooltip.light-theme {
  color: #26323d;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 4px rgba(154, 161, 177, 0.15),
    0 4px 80px -8px rgba(36, 40, 47, 0.25),
    0 4px 4px -2px rgba(91, 94, 105, 0.15);
  background-color: white;
}

.tippy-backdrop {
  background-color: white;
}

.tippy-roundarrow {
  fill: white;
}

/* Default (sharp) arrow */
.tippy-popper[x-placement^='top'] .tippy-tooltip.light-theme .tippy-arrow {
  border-top-color: #fff;
}
.tippy-popper[x-placement^='bottom'] .tippy-tooltip.light-theme .tippy-arrow {
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
.tippy-popper[x-placement^='left'] .tippy-tooltip.light-theme .tippy-arrow {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}
.tippy-popper[x-placement^='right'] .tippy-tooltip.light-theme .tippy-arrow {
  border-right-color: #fff;
}
/* Round arrow */
.tippy-tooltip.light-theme .tippy-roundarrow {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```js
/* TOC 
part one - Swiper instilaze
part two - photoswipe instilaze
part three - photoswipe define options
part four - extra code (update swiper index when image close and micro changes)

/* 1 of 4 : SWIPER ################################### */
var mySwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  // If swiper loop is true set photoswipe counterEl: false (line 175 her)
  loop: true,
  /* slidesPerView || auto - if you want to set width by css like flickity.js layout - in this case width:80% by CSS */
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  spaceBetween: 10,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slideToClickedSlide: false,
  autoplay: { /* remove/comment to stop autoplay  */
    delay: 3000,
    disableOnInteraction: false /* true by deafult */
  },
  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function(index, className) {
      return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + "</span>";
    }
  },
  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  // keyboard control
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  }
});

// 2 of 4 : PHOTOSWIPE #######################################
// https://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html //

var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {
  // parse slide data (url, title, size ...) from DOM elements
  // (children of gallerySelector)
  var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
    var thumbElements = el.childNodes,
        numNodes = thumbElements.length,
        items = [],
        figureEl,
        linkEl,
        size,
        item;

    for (var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
      figureEl = thumbElements[i]; // <figure> element

      // include only element nodes
      if (figureEl.nodeType !== 1) {
        continue;
      }

      linkEl = figureEl.children[0]; // <a> element

      size = linkEl.getAttribute("data-size").split("x");

      // create slide object
      item = {
        src: linkEl.getAttribute("href"),
        w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
        h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
      };

      if (figureEl.children.length > 1) {
        // <figcaption> content
        item.title = figureEl.children[1].innerHTML;
      }

      if (linkEl.children.length > 0) {
        // <img> thumbnail element, retrieving thumbnail url
        item.msrc = linkEl.children[0].getAttribute("src");
      }

      item.el = figureEl; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn
      items.push(item);
    }

    return items;
  };

  // find nearest parent element
  var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
    return el && (fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn));
  };

  // triggers when user clicks on thumbnail
  var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);

    var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

    // find root element of slide
    var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
      return el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === "LI";
    });

    if (!clickedListItem) {
      return;
    }

    // find index of clicked item by looping through all child nodes
    // alternatively, you may define index via data- attribute
    var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode,
        childNodes = clickedListItem.parentNode.childNodes,
        numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
        nodeIndex = 0,
        index;

    for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
      if (childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) {
        continue;
      }

      if (childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
        index = nodeIndex;
        break;
      }
      nodeIndex++;
    }

    if (index >= 0) {
      // open PhotoSwipe if valid index found
      openPhotoSwipe(index, clickedGallery);
    }
    return false;
  };

  // parse picture index and gallery index from URL (#&pid=1&gid=2)
  var photoswipeParseHash = function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
        params = {};

    if (hash.length < 5) {
      return params;
    }

    var vars = hash.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
      if (!vars[i]) {
        continue;
      }
      var pair = vars[i].split("=");
      if (pair.length < 2) {
        continue;
      }
      params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }

    if (params.gid) {
      params.gid = parseInt(params.gid, 10);
    }

    return params;
  };

  var openPhotoSwipe = function(
  index,
   galleryElement,
   disableAnimation,
   fromURL
  ) {
    var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll(".pswp")[0],
        gallery,
        options,
        items;

    items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);

    // #################### 3/4 define photoswipe options (if needed) #################### 
    // https://photoswipe.com/documentation/options.html //
    options = {
      /* "showHideOpacity" uncomment this If dimensions of your small thumbnail don't match dimensions of large image */
      //showHideOpacity:true,

      // Buttons/elements
      closeEl: true,
      captionEl: true,
      fullscreenEl: true,
      zoomEl: true,
      shareEl: false,
      counterEl: false,
      arrowEl: true,
      preloaderEl: true,
      // define gallery index (for URL)
      galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute("data-pswp-uid"),
      getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
        // See Options -> getThumbBoundsFn section of documentation for more info
        var thumbnail = items[index].el.getElementsByTagName("img")[0], // find thumbnail
            pageYScroll =
            window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect();

        return { x: rect.left, y: rect.top + pageYScroll, w: rect.width };
      }
    };

    // PhotoSwipe opened from URL
    if (fromURL) {
      if (options.galleryPIDs) {
        // parse real index when custom PIDs are used
        // http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#custom-pid-in-url
        for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
          if (items[j].pid == index) {
            options.index = j;
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        // in URL indexes start from 1
        options.index = parseInt(index, 10) - 1;
      }
    } else {
      options.index = parseInt(index, 10);
    }

    // exit if index not found
    if (isNaN(options.index)) {
      return;
    }

    if (disableAnimation) {
      options.showAnimationDuration = 0;
    }

    // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
    gallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
    gallery.init();

    /* ########### PART 4 - EXTRA CODE  ########### */
    /* EXTRA CODE (NOT FROM photoswipe CORE) - 
    1/2. UPDATE SWIPER POSITION TO THE CURRENT ZOOM_IN IMAGE (BETTER UI) */
    // photoswipe event: Gallery unbinds events
    // (triggers before closing animation)
    gallery.listen("unbindEvents", function() {
      // This is index of current photoswipe slide
      var getCurrentIndex = gallery.getCurrentIndex();
      // Update position of the slider
      mySwiper.slideTo(getCurrentIndex, false);
      // 2/2. Start swiper autoplay (on close - if swiper autoplay is true)
      mySwiper.autoplay.start();
    });
    // 2/2. Extra Code (Not from photo) - swiper autoplay stop when image zoom */
    gallery.listen('initialZoomIn', function() {
      if(mySwiper.autoplay.running){
        mySwiper.autoplay.stop();
      }
    });
  };

  // loop through all gallery elements and bind events
  var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll(gallerySelector);

  for (var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
    galleryElements[i].setAttribute("data-pswp-uid", i + 1);
    galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
  }

  // Parse URL and open gallery if it contains #&pid=3&gid=1
  var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
  if (hashData.pid && hashData.gid) {
    openPhotoSwipe(hashData.pid, galleryElements[hashData.gid - 1], true, true);
  }
};

// execute above function
initPhotoSwipeFromDOM(".my-gallery");
```

https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/XNpJaX/

Answer (score 0):

instead using photoswipe, use only swiper like in this demo I did make:
<-------html------>

```
<div class="swiper-container horizontal">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-container vertical">
              <div class="swiper-wrapper vertical">
                <div class="swiper-slide vertical">
                  Slide 1
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide vertical">
                  Slide 1.1
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide vertical">
                  Slide 1.2
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide vertical">
                  Slide 1.3
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-pagination vertical"></div>
            </div></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination horizontal"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container.horizontal', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination.horizontal',
        direction: 'horizontal',
        slidesPerView: 1,
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        mousewheelControl: true
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container.vertical', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        direction: 'vertical',
        slidesPerView: 1,
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        mousewheelControl: true
    });
    </script>
```

<---------html end----------->

<--------css----------->

```
html, body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;
        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

<---------css end------------->

https://jsfiddle.net/120ngmoh/